# Animations Path by Path in RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

I have to make several animations starting from SVG, what I'm doing is saving the SVG with each modified position so it becomes easy for the animation Raphaeljs, I'm using a converter from SVG to RaphaelJS and generates me some groups of elements that can not handle for the next SVG with the modified position.

full code in jsfiddle

```
Layer_1_1_.animate({
    path: "M 410.251,139.304 410.617,142.129 270.996,202.417 116.224,194.09 115.859,191.263 264.412,163.038 z"
}, 2000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxyJN/)

Comment: Those online converters don't necessarily form the right structure to allow animation you want. This is supposed to be a tipping scale, right?

Comment: actually do not know, all the tutorials told me to seek a way to convert path to RaphaelJS

Comment: Take a look at this animation- http://jsfiddle.net/Cy8DQ/

Comment: I think the problem is in getting the patch like this guy does not know why mine is generated this way.